# Safe use of multiple scope in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Safe use of multiple scope in the controller.

In the controller I need to call one of the three scopes. How to do it safely?

If I send params `scope=destroy_all` this will remove all entries.

Method in controller:

```
def index
  @campaigns = Campaign.send(params[:scope] || 'all')
end
```

Scopes:

```
scope :ended, -> {where ("date(current_timestamp) - date(created_at) > ends_at")}
scope :active, -> {where ("date(current_timestamp) - date(created_at) < ends_at")}
```

In views:

```
.btn-group
  = link_to _('Ended Campaigns'), admin_campaigns_path(scope: :ended), class: 'btn btn-default'
  = link_to _('Ob-going Campaigns'), admin_campaigns_path(scope: :active), class: 'btn btn-default'
  = link_to _('All Campaigns'), admin_campaigns_path(scope: :all), class: 'btn btn-default'
```

Comment: don't do that! it's too insecure, at least put a before_filter to only allow 'ended' or 'active' as posible values for params[:scope]. params[:scope] = nil unless ['ended','active'].include?(params[:scope])

Comment: @arieljuod I didn't understand about before_filter, can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a before filter

```
class YourController
  before_filter :filter_scopes, only: :index

  def index
    @campaigns = Campaign.send(params[:scope] || 'all')
  end

  private
  def filter_scopes
    params[:scope] = nil unless ['ended','active'].include?(params[:scope])
  end
end
```

that way you are sure that only "ended", "active" and "all" are the allowed values when calling the scope

EDIT: this is an old answer, I'd like to add that `before_filter` was replaced with `before_action` on newer rails versions. Also, I now think that there might be a more elegant solution for this without a before_action and without changing the params hash, just add a "getter" for the scope value:

```
class YourController
  def index
    @campaigns = Campaign.send(get_scope_from_params)
  end

  def get_scope_from_params
    ['ended','active'].include?(params[:scope]) ? params[:scope] : 'all'
  end
end
```

You can even make it a helper method if you need to use it on the view. I think it's better not to modify params hash (unless you are sure that's what you want) and it also makes more sense to have a "getter" method than a before_action method since what you actually want is to get a valid scope name.

Answer (score 1):

You can whitelist your scopes, like this:

```
@campaigns = if %w(ended active).include?(params[:scope])
               Campaign.public_send(params[:scope])
             else
               Campaign.all
             end
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible somehow, through `strong params` to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is too insecure and cryptic to leave the scope application to the user input.

I would do it as follows

```
def index
  @campaigns = Campaign.all
  if params[:scope] == 'ended'
    @campaign = @campaign.ended
  elsif params[:scope] == 'active'
    @campaign = @campaign.active
  end
end
```